# Flutter error: Unable to locate gradlew script

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle

I can't run all of my flutter apps, because in the console appears everytime this error message:

```
Downloading Gradle Wrapper...                                       1,2s
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G960F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Finished with error: Unable to locate gradlew script. Please check that C:\Users\...\android\gradlew.bat exists or that C:\Users\...\android can be read.
```

I try to fix this problem more than ten hours and don't find a solution.

Comment: delete the .gradle folder located here `C:\Users\yourPcName\.gradle` containing the unfinished file and try again

Answer (score 0):

I will advise you to check your pc properly for unwanted programs. Something is preventing your pc from running the Gradle. I had the same issue only to realize that antivirus was installed on my pc alongside a cd burner that I just installed. Check for any antivirus that might be preventing Gradle from running.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error initially. While creating a flutter application from scratch I just ran the default flutter application which is a counter app in a flutter. I faced the same issue at first. If you are in this same context as described earlier the following could be the solution

1.Java 8 is more suitable for the flutter/android development. The next versions of java have some exceptions. I used the Java 14 and stuck at this issue for some time

2. The next could be the JAVA_HOME path in your environment variables. If it is not provided the set the JAVA_HOME path.
3. Run flutter --doctor and check the requirements if satisfied like Android SDK is updated or not, upgrade flutter if required. In some cases having good Internet connection also plays a role in this issue some times.

These are the major points to be satisfied in order to get rid of this error. Mostly this could be the a solution or part of it.

Answer (score 0):

**The error suggests** that something is ***preventing gradle to run properly on your machine***. Check whether you have any unwanted programs or anti-virus on your machine running that might be preventing gradle to run. If so, **remove or stop those programs / anti-virus and try again.**

After that, delete the **.gradle** folder located here `C:\Users\yourPcName\.gradle` containing the unfinished file and try again . It will work now .

You can also manually download Gradle and map it in Android studio , Learn more with this article [here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/) .

> Warning, the gradle versions change quickly, so make sure you manually
> downloaded the exact version that flutter wanted to download and the
> download failed.  Download the gradle [here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/) and then replace it in the
> gradle folder.
> C:\Users\yourPcName\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-x.x.x-all

---

If it still doesn't work,
Try to run `flutter --doctor`

From a console window that has the Flutter directory in the path (see above), run the following command to see if there are any platform dependencies you need to complete the setup:

```
C:\src\flutter> : flutter doctor
```

This command checks your environment and displays a report of the status of your Flutter installation. Check the output carefully for other software you might need to install or further tasks to perform (shown in bold text).

You can learn more [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#run-flutter-doctor) :

> *If flutter doctor itself doesn't work, then know that flutter is not installed on your machine (or you forgot to add it to the environment
> variable).*

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem and I made something to run my app on android
tried to open anything on android files and android studio ask me if I want to open for editing android file in android studio then click on it and it will open android project then click run [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tehs.png)