# Flutter error: Unable to locate gradlew script. Check if bat file exists or the android folder is readable

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I've been trying to fix this error since a week now.Somebody please help me fix this...

I have installed flutter and its working fine.
Installed Android Studio 3.6 and also downloaded Android SDK and other tools.(No errors when i execute flutter doctor)

However when i am trying to run the sample first flutter app on my real device (Lenovo Vibe K5 plus android 5.1.1) i get the following error

```
   Unable to locate gradlew script. Please check that C:\Users\...\android\gradlew.bat exists or that C:\Users\...\app1\android can be read.
```

And when i run project for the first time i get this :

```
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1
```

What is the problem? How do i fix this?

Comment: Do you install SDK for android 5.1.1 in android studio? [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms)

Comment: So does this mean that the problem might be because of my device android version? I'm actually running it on real device... because my emulator doesn't work because of some graphics driver issues... But I even tried on android 6...doesn't work

Comment: Your question has already been asked. Here is the answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65450422/14762762)

Answer (score 0):

i think you deleted `.gradle` file,
you may need to uninstall each and every file related to android studio and install it again.