# Flutter: Could not create task ':generateLockfiles'. Problem with gradlew.bat in Windows

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

Error is: "The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not create task ':generateLockfiles'.
Cannot run program "C:\Users...\android/gradlew.bat". CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified."

Flutter doctor shows only one problem: It sais that the android phone emulator has issues to run. And that is of course the case when I have problems in my android/gradle folder/files.
Don't know what I can do here...

Answer (score 1):

[build.gradle error: Could not create tastk ':generateLockfiles'. in Flutter project but App is running normal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73357365/build-gradle-error-could-not-create-tastk-generatelockfiles-in-flutter-proj?newreg=ef235e58ba1945499a088048405e8274)

According to these answers I have first run the 'flutter doctor/ flutter clean / flutter pub get ' and those were not enough for m situation. So I have also opened the project in Android studio and then open it with VS Code or etc. It worked at the end, Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

- Just open the project in `Android Studio`, that should update any files you may need in the `android\build.gradle` file. *Important note*: Open the actual `android/` folder, not just your root Flutter project.
- You will see probably something like this:

  [image]
- After the update, re-run VSCode and the Android Emulator. You may need to re-start your system.
- The changes were as follows:

  [image]

#### Related Issues

- [[tool_crash] ArgumentError: Invalid argument(s): Cannot find executable for C:\Users\krimtel-3\AndroidStudioProjects\shakuntalagroup\android\gradlew.bat](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56975)
- [Flutter error: Unable to locate gradlew script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59885983/flutter-error-unable-to-locate-gradlew-script/65450422#65450422)