# The supplied phased action failed with an exception. Could not create task ':generateLockfiles'

Tags: flutter, firebase

The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not create task ':generateLockfiles'.
Process 'command 'C:\Users\lemo\StudioProjects\tesssssssstt\android/gradlew.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

The supplied phased action failed with an exception.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Take a look to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77456841/7389293 And please, provide more information about the problem.